# What kind of database/DBA questions does the SO community want to keep?

Tags: discussion, migration

It [is likely](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267/are-we-ready-to-leave-public-beta-and-launch) that [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) will be leaving beta in the near future. While the site has been in beta, questions have been migrated ["only for exceptional circumstances"](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167/since-questions-wont-necessarily-get-migrated-here-can-we-copy-them/168#168), but that will change once the site is launched.

Obviously questions should only be migrated if the SO community would prefer them to be - so I thought it would be good to ask what kind of questions you would prefer to remain here (even if they are [a good fit for dba.se](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-kind-of-questions-are-allowed-on-database-administrators/86#86)) and which questions you would prefer to lose.

I'm only referring to *new* questions that would be migrated if they had a better home but currently are tolerated because they don't, and are not so far off-topic to be closed.

Please post links to existing questions, along with your rationale for proposing that such a question should be kept on SO or that it should be migrated (bearing in mind no-one is proposing actually migrating *old* questions). **I have added two answers myself as examples and marked them CW.**

Comment: I am not sure there is a definitive answer, especially if the questions are on-topic in both the sites.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - If a question really is on-topic in both sites, I imagine it will just stay put. "on-topic" is an evolving concept to some degree - I wonder if you'd prefer to restrict it a little given the opportunity?

Comment: To make an example, Drupal questions are on-topic on Stack Overflow and on Drupal Answers; if somebody asks a Drupal question on Stack Overflow, you cannot say "this question is for Drupal Answers." There are probably questions about which module to choose that are not specific about programming, but those questions have been "tolerated" and they will not migrated to Drupal Answers.

Comment: This would be a very good question to ask on Meta Server Fault. It seems like the two would be 100% overlap in topic.

Comment: @Jon - good idea. SF post [here](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1855/what-kind-of-database-dba-questions-does-the-sf-community-want-to-keep)

Answer (score 11):

Personally I'm not in favour of migrating *old* questions to a new site. There are several reasons for this:

1. If it's off topic then why wasn't it just closed in the first place?
2. Is it going to help the question get better answers by migrating it? Unlikely as either it's already got an accepted answer or the OP has abandoned it.
3. Is it going to create a duplicate? There's a good chance that old Stack Overflow questions were reasked on the new site as part of the private (or even public) beta.
4. Is it really off topic on Stack Overflow? If it would fit either site then why not just leave it where it is.

However, *new* questions should be migrated to the most appropriate site - bearing in mind the golden rule - **don't migrate crap.**

Comment: I was only referring to new questions (I've edited the question to make that clear).

Comment: Note that what has been considered as off-topic has changed over time. Something that is off-topic now might not've been back when it was originally posted.

Comment: @Lasse - I guess it will continue to change? Part of the rationale for posting this question is suggest a debate on SO about whether it might be good to tighten up the criteria for database-related questions to allow better focus on programming

Comment: Yep, I agree with all of that, I was just noting the fact :)

Answer (score 8):

Whatever you do don't migrate the ones that are technical programming questions.
If they can fit on either site, then they don't need to be migrated.

Comment: Am I right to assume this will include most straight SQL questions?

Comment: @Jack, I certainly hope that no one intends to migrate SQL questions.  SQL questions are still on-topic for SO.

Comment: For clarity I've added an answer suggesting migration of certain SQL questions. Please downvote if you disagree

Comment: My view is advanced SQL, query optimiser, indexing, security etc are better on dba.se. They may be "programming" but most programmers don't care about these topics...

Answer (score 5):

I vote for all the new table structure questions to be migrated. Questions that don't have much to do with the database itself, like establishing a connection, should stay, since they are more programming than dba.

Comment: New table structure is a design question that developers need to deal with not just dbas

Comment: My view is advanced SQL, query optimiser, indexing, security etc are better on dba.se. They may be "programming" but most programmers don't care about these topics...

Answer (score 5):

[This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4485/how-do-i-group-results-in-batches-of-consecutive-rows-with-the-same-module) was asked on dba.se

My accepted answer uses two levels of analytic (windowing) functions to get the desired result in a single SQL statement. Not all RDBMSs provide analytic functions but the question was specifically for Oracle which is one of those that do.

If it had instead been asked on SO, it should have been migrated to dba.se because it is a specialized SQL question more suited to that site.

*please note I'm not necessarily saying I really think questions like this should be migrated, rather I'm posting an answer to get feedback on what the SO community want. Please upvote/downvote this answer according to your preference*

Comment: It's not necessarily possible for SO users - or moderators - to know when a question will be better off on DBAs. If you (or another DBAs regular) happen upon a SO question languishing that you think could be well-answered on DBAs and suggest the move, that's going to be a lot more reliable than asking SO users to migrate stuff with advanced / specialized SQL. And naturally, a question that's already been answer *well* on SO probably shouldn't be moved at all.

Comment: There are a few users with high rep on both sites who are known to the SO mods and flag questions they think would be better on dba.se

Answer (score 3):

[This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/9448/1396) was asked on SO and then migrated to dba.se

Since the migration the OP has registered on dba.se and responded to a comment by editing the question with more information - and there have been two detailed answers from dba.se regulars (one of them me as it happens).

The answers since the migration ([here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9480/1396) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9484/1396)) are very different to the ones from before, reflecting the different focus of the site.

One of the SO users who had already answered before the migration flagged the question to let us know he was of the opinion that the migration should not have happened.

OTOH I suggest this is an example of a good migration because the question was in need of some in-depth treatment. Please vote up if you agree and down if you disagree.

*please note I'm posting here to get feedback on what the SO community want. It doesn't matter what my opinion is, but yours matters very much. Please upvote/downvote this answer according to your preference*

Comment: I flagged it. It's a programming question by a programmer, requiring an answer appropriate to programming - nothing to do with database administration.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Jeffrey. One thing I feel is sometimes a source of confusion is that dba.se is [not just](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq) for database *administration*. Of course that is nothing to do with whether a question is on-topic on SO - that is for SO to decide.