# Migration of [data-warehouse] and [database-design] questions from SO to Database Administrators?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, migration

Seems that [data-warehouse] and [database-design] questions are being migrated from StackOverflow by (?)
to Database Administrators -- **[here is an example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/fact-table-design-level-or-contribution-measures)**.

- Is this now an established policy?
- Is there a rule when a question is being migrated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Speaking from the standpoint of someone "in the know" over at [dba.se], I would encourage you to first check the FAQ (which to my own fault is lacking in replete defintion, but we've recently held mod elections, so we should be sprucing that up .. soonish) but then to follow it up with a brief visit to our meta, wherein the FAQ tab of the Questions page on that meta (which is the canonical-to-date place to find such questions, as it would be here on Meta.Stack Overflow) shows this Q:

> [What kind of questions are allowed on Database Administrators ?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-kind-of-questions-are-allowed-on-database-administrators)

We see what questions are encouraged to be asked there.

---

However, what you're really wanting to know is: We've been asking for selected questions to be migrated, because we wanted to build a better core set of questions of the variety that we wanted to see, and we haven't asked for questions to be migrated en-masse because cherry picking gives us what we want and keeps things clean.

So, does this mean "yay, migrate all the things"? No, not at all. But if you're curious about if your question would be better suited on a site dedicated to getting help from senior DBAs (whether they be NoSQL or RDBMS guys) and you can't tell from browsing the site first (hey, your question could already be well answered!) then feel free to ask on http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com or pop into the chatroom:

> https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-clustered-index

HTH (but it won't have helped at all, I'm sure)

Comment: Here is my point: Top three [database-design] answerers on SO have answered between 120 and 320 questions each. In total there are currently only about 150 of those on DBA -- even I have answered more than that on SO. Similar with [data-warehouse]. So, why do you feel that these questions should be **migrated away** from SO?

Comment: Because when most of those were asked/answered, [dba.se] wasn't even a potential migration target. Only your most recent ~60 answers would the questions likely have even been eligible for migration in the first place. That's 60 out of more than 300. That's why "now" and not "before". However, if your entire question boils down to "why migrate them at all" then I can only shake my head. That's the whole point to having more specialized sites, where we can better separate out the wheat from the chaff. We need less bazaar and more specialist alley.

Comment: What does that mean? Who needs that? Developers obviously do not -- they have asked those questions on SO and had them answered. I do not see top 5 SO answerers in these categories on DBA exchange? What prevents you to answer those questions on SO?

Comment: Did a quick check. Out of top 20 SO answerers in [database-design] only two are on DBA exchange list (top 5 are not). I do recognize few more names. Similar with [data-warehouse]. So remind me again, who thinks that these questions should be migrated?

Comment: The answer is that we have professional DBAs asking to migrate those questions over, because we want to create a site where developers can get answers FROM PROFESSIONAL DBAs, much as they would at a jobsite. Sometimes you need to ask a DBA, sometimes you can get away with asking a developer. You may have noticed that sometimes people ask questions on [so] that don't really pertain to [so] properly, such as the ones that get migrated to [sf] or [su] even tho they could get properly answered on [so]. I bet you're also upset about [programmers.se] being a separate site huh?

Comment: Additionally, while I'm glad that you recognize a few names on the top of the list, I recognize more of them. I and several professional DBAs that are looking to illustrate the types of questions that would be better answered by professional DBAs than by developers are the ones that are making those decisions on what should be migrated. Do you feel that the DBA site is somehow not a better place to find specific topical experts to answer those questions? Would you rather just hope that a developer knows enough about databases here on [so] to answer your questions?

Comment: I for one joined the stacks because I recognized the benefit of having local experts in a concentrated system that I could tap for specific domain expertise. I don't have a problem with the idea that experts can help me better than non-experts. That is why [dba.se] was created. To give a place where experts could be found. Many of the top users on [dba.se] are the go-to consultants or they have MVPs or their equivalents, they are the ones whose articles you read in magazines. Being able to pick their brains is something I'm proud to be part of.

Comment: So your claim is that people answering these two database related question-groups on SO are not knowledgable enough because they do not qualify as professional database administrators -- at least until they join db.se. So why don't you just answer on SO and vote up-down? And what prevents user for going directly to db.se and asking there?

Comment: I did not say that. I said that we want to create a stronger base of questions on [dba.se] and have asked that those questions get migrated. By asking to migrate questions, eventually people like you, who are familiar with the topics, and people who are new but looking, will find the site. We want to provide a better experience, by focusing our effots. I'm not saying it's _wrong_ to ask them here, I'm saying it's _better_ to ask them there. I'm saying that sometimes I can ask a dev, but sometimes I have to goto my dba.

Comment: Do keep in mind that this question is about migrating questions **away** from SO for two very specific tags.

Comment: Yes, it's about migrating away database questions that DBAs would be more likely to answer properly than devs. What did I miss?

Comment: @Damir Sudarevic: How many questions about database design are not tagged "database-design"? Two example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008016/best-database-design-for-product-with-different-price-for-each-attributes/6008068#6008068 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/5620476/27535 "Normalization", "Database" etc cover it too

Comment: @gbn true, but nothing prevents you, nor me, to edit tags. You have answered ~4300 question on SO, ~100 on [database-design]. Do you think that you can do a better job at it if they were migrated do db.se?

Comment: @Damir Sudarevic: I'd see them more easily. Then we can find out

Comment: @gbn, well then I will defer to you judgement and bow out of this discussion.

Comment: @Damir Sudarevic: That's a quite passive-aggressive non-answer. Now, are you going to come along to the site and answer? Personally, I haven't done much DW modelling and I'd like to know more about the subject. If not, why not?

Comment: @gbn; no, please do not look at it that way. My point is that if a top SO contributor(s) in the [tag] feel(s) that these should be migrated, then it should be so. I do design daily, but no administration at all (almost)  -- so I will stick to the SO except for me asking questions.

Comment: Wait, so you do database design, but you never consult a DBA to make sure that you're doing the _best_ design for the database? You do realize that being a DBA is more than knowing what the logfiles mean, right?

Comment: Do you code? Or just design? I dba, design and code.

Answer (score 3):

> - Is this now an established policy?
> - Is there a rule when a question is being migrated?

AFAIK there is no rule or policy on this, it boils down to what the SO community wants and whether there are questions they would like to send to a better home if there was one - but over on [dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) our intention is to provide a good home for:

- advanced database-related questions
- SE users on other sites who could do a great job answering these questions!

Looking through some of your answers, I think you'd be a valuable contributor on dba.se should you choose to share yourself between us and SO - personally, I hope you will consider doing so, and ultimately I think you would be very happy on the site as it grows and becomes better known

Comment: you may also be interested in [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100507/what-kind-of-database-dba-questions-does-the-so-community-want-to-keep) mSO post

Comment: Most kind of you Jack.

Comment: @DamirSudarevic - I'm with Jack on this. Despite the unfortunate name (which many of us are [pushing to change](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/270/2660)), we have plenty of activity related to design and we would love some more experts in the DW arena like yourself on DBA.SE.