# Are any SQL questions valid for StackOverflow now that there's Database Administrators?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why migrate questions that are on-topic for both DBA and SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117345/why-migrate-questions-that-are-on-topic-for-both-dba-and-so)

Apparently, this question '[Maximum value from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152104/maximum-value-from-multiple-tables/9152175#9152175)' (a plain old SQL programming question with not even a question about indexing to justify 'database administration') is no longer suitable for StackOverflow.

## I protest!

If every SQL question is going to be transferred to Database Administrators, then life on StackOverflow will be much less interesting to me.

How do we get the question migrated back?  I don't have any reputation worth mentioning over there (most of what I've earned come from that one question being migrated).  That means I can't do anything emphatic towards getting it migrated back to SO where it belongs with the 70,000 or so other SQL questions.  I don't have the time or energy to frequent another site on a routine basis.

I've flagged the question in DB Admins - but the StackExchange sites should not be preempting perfectly good (SQL) programming questions from StackOverflow.

Comment: I recently suffered this same exact situation with a [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140181/what-happened-to-the-50-points-bounty-i-awarded-a-user-before-my-question-was-mi) I asked on SO[informix], which also included a 50-point bounty which was awarded, but subsequently stripped from the user. I would like for my question to be returned to SO[Informix].