# SO points changed (+50) for no reason

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, bounties, deleted-questions

My rep on SO went up by 50 just after the site was offline. It says that I get 
+50 for the question [Object Technolgy / Object-Oriented Technology implemented in Relational Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4503959/447356) (deleted, 10K only) but I clearly didn't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You had previously offered a 50 point bounty on that question, which the system seems to have refunded you when the question was deleted.

There's a related Meta question [asking about bounties on deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145329/when-a-question-that-had-bounties-is-deleted-are-they-automatically-refunded), but it doesn't currently have an official response (although Shog's [answer to another bounty question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140181/what-happened-to-the-50-points-bounty-i-awarded-a-user-before-my-question-was-mi/140185#140185) suggests this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)).

**Update:** As of February 13, 2018, the bounty reputation is [no longer refunded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306966/changes-to-bounty-rules-removal-of-double-rep-retention-blocking-of-owner-dele) upon question deletion if the bounty awardee gets to retain it (because it scored +3 and was visible for at least 60 days).

Comment: Maybe it only refunds for questions preserving the reputation in the first place i.e. score +3 or more and visible for at least 60 days prior to deletion? That's the case with my question and this one as well.