# Unexplained reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I recently received 50 rep, though having a look at where it might have come from, I have no idea.

[image]

I am a member of multiple sites, and there is no indication of where the rep might have come from. The amount seemed slightly unusual too; 50 rep with no explanation. I know in some cases rep can be "re-awarded" from downvoted answers that have been deleted, but 50 rep seems way too high for this too be the case. Can anyone else clarify what this might have come from?

**EDIT:** It's happened again.

[image]

As we can see, another unexplained 50 rep has appeared on my profile. I had a bit of a poke around, and this time it seems to have appeared on my Scifi & Fantasy profile, but once again, it is completely unexplained.

Does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: Did you have an answer that got undeleted?  (Part of some kind of question undeletion?)

Comment: No that I'm aware of. To my knowledge the only questions/answers of mine that were ever deleted were deleted by me, and it was because they weren't very good.

Comment: Might be a question you placed a  bounty on got deleted. In such case the bounty is revoked. What do you see in your reputation tab in profile page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know what site it happened on it's easy enough to check the reputation tab there for an entry, but if you participate on several sites that's not very helpful -- walking through profiles looking for the rep gain is tedious.

One thing you can do is to look at the [reputation tab on your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/3690277/ben?tab=reputation).  If the change came from a single event like a user being removed, a post being undeleted, or a bounty being refunded, you should see a jump in one site on the graph.  (I don't think this graph is up-to-the-minute correct, so you may have to wait a few hours.)  Once you see *which* site had the jump, you can [look there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253920/162102).

Comment: Found it - "+50 - Apr 20 - removed - packs/instances not opening on the ATlauncher" To my knowledge it's not a Question I asked, and I don't believe I have enough reputation on Arqade (the profile this rep is from) to see deleted questions/answers (there is no link the question)

Comment: Hmm, that's odd -- to get +50 from a *deletion* implies that whatever it was, it was heavily downvoted (deletion cancels rep changes in both directions, unless the post is old).  Does that sound like something you would have answered or placed a bounty on?

Comment: It's possible, but I couldn't be sure. I tried searching for the question title but it returned 0 results (clearly, after having been deleted).

Comment: You might need to ask someone with 10k rep for help (assuming you have a link).

Comment: Might be bounty related, as per this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172556/so-points-changed-50-for-no-reason

Answer (score 2):

Go to your profile (for example: [My Profile in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3906965/abhishek?tab=reputation)) and select reputation tab. Scroll down and untick/tick `show removed post`, as shown in below pic. You should be able to see the reason for the unexplained reputation :)

[image]

To addon, sometimes the reputation center sometimes shows cumulative reputation earned since last time you checked it.