How to get bounty back if a question is closed?
I started a bounty over on Stack Overflow that regarded Docker Compose and networking, and then the question got closed. Someone with the right authority regarded it was a networking question and not suitable for Stack Overflow.
I am not necassrily disputing that, but I would like to get my bounty rep back.
How can I file a dispute with StackExchange to get my bounty back since the question was closed? Or, ideally, the question would be re-opened. But either way: (1) I'd like the bounty back, or (2) I'd like the question to be re-opened. But having the question closed and bounty still lost feels like a lose-lose situation.
According to this answer, questions with bounties on them cannot be closed.

They were unable to be closed until earlier this year, so the linked answer is outdated

That's great, the notes off of that link still say I should be repaid my bounty.


I can't find such a claim on that page 2. The FAQ which the answer refers to also doesn't say that. What says the bounty should be repaid, so we can correct it?


Honestly, it looks like this whole thing is poorly designed but it's unclear what happens if the question is closed after the bounty period is over. The answer on MSE points at another answer proposing a solution but that "solution" has no indication of what happens when the question is still closed when the bounty ends.

I'm a little confused with the downvotes - it shows a potential issue with the system as designed, and it feels valid in context.

@JourneymanGeek I agree, so I upvoted this quality question (and your comment). My guess as to the reason for all the downvotes is that there is a long history of knee-jerk downvoting on Stack Exchange to anything that sounds even a little bit like complaining or a mild rant.  The exception appears to be when the target of the complaints is Stack Exchange management or staff members.

I'd say the process would be flagging the question - and making a case for refunding the bounty. Alternatively, using the per site meta to make a case for reopening the question.
I'd encourage you to specifically ask about this question and your options on meta.stackoverflow.com with respect of that
I feel like those are independent of the broader issue though.
Historically bounties were sometimes used 'tactically' as a way to prevent a question from being closed. It could be a loophole, mitigated just a little by the 48 hour delay.
With the current system, as a moderator, my first instinct would be to refund the bounty and perhaps with how the system is designed now, that's the fairest option with no answers.
Maybe I'm overcomplicating things but - I'd also want to consider - are there answers posted in good faith that attempt to answer the question, and were there close votes before the bounty was placed. The first would be in consideration of people posting their answers in good faith, and the second, considering if the bounty was placed tactically.
I'm fond of saying that you're spending reputation to advertise to get an answer. The current system sort of creates a situation where you can't do the latter.
I'd say that ideally an automatic refund for a closure for being off topic, and potentially other classes of closures where OP isn't involved in voting would be a fair option. We don't have that now - but I feel like that's the right way to go.

If the bounty expires and the OP deletes the post won't they get the bounty back? If so isn't that pretty simple for them to do themselves?

I've actually no idea if it actually does that - the change wasn't documented very well I suspect.

@RobertLongson Not that I'm aware of? The bounty recipient (if any) loses the bounty value but I don't think you get the rep back if the formerly-bountied question is deleted at some point in the future. The policy has always been "bounties are for attention, you got your week of attention, you don't get the rep back" - The only reason closure is an exception is because you're not getting your "week of attention".

That said, the FAQ says that it is refunded if the bounty award was not retained by the recipient... so if the question is deleted and there is no answer to earn the bounty, I guess it would? But That's a bit of an outlier in the normal "practice"... it also makes it less likely an asker would bother to fix the question - and if the question can be closed, and the asker wants to deleted it, they should be able to - which I'm not sure is the case?

@Catija Per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172556/so-points-changed-50-for-no-reason and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work - If a question on which you have started or awarded a bounty on later gets deleted, then in most cases, your reputation is refunded. Of course the OP may not be able to delete it if it has a bounty, it may require a moderator or some 20K users.

@RobertLongson Sure, which I noted in my second comment... :P But in this case, the OP seems to be continuing to work on the question and disagrees that closure was appropriate at all - so it seems unlikely they want to delete it, which means they're hoping it will get reopened... but at that point, they will have nothing left to bounty it again or award someone who might actually be helping them solve their problem.

@Catija it's not been nominated for reopening and given this mod answer to a similar question about docker-compose I think it's unlikely to be reopened.

I've started a discussion on Meta Stack Overflow for this case. Would be great if you chimed in.

This very much reflects real life: if you get what you paid for - you should be happy with it, if you don't get what you paid for - you should ask for a refund. Having the question closed mid-bounty period very much resembles the latter (I aked for visibility and I didn't get it), so I too think it should be eleigible for a refund.
